# Works on PHP but not with script

Tags: php, jquery

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0cGZ.png)

I have this code that works perfectly. The dropdown field contains options. But when I try to create a new line using the "Add More" button, the dropdown is not working. Please check the output.

```
    <select name="name[]"/>
    <?php
    echo "<option SELECTED DISABLED>SELECT CUSTOMER</option>";
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
    echo "<option value='$result[description]'>" . $result['description'] . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>/td>  
<td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
```

with a script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><select name="name[]"/><?php echo "<option SELECTED DISABLED>SELECT CUSTOMER</option>"; while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){ echo "<option value='$result[description]'>" . $result['description'] . "</option>";}?></select></td>         <td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
      });
```

But the #add doesn't create a new like of input form. I believe there's something wrong with #dynamic_field script and I fail to find it. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Now to the question, PHP is a server side language so can't be parsed inside a browser directly. Your script snippet won't work unless you dynamically fetch result form a processed php script via Ajax

Comment: You're using a self-closing `<select />`, you should be using `<select name="name[]">` (without the `/`). Then your `<option>`s will actually be *inside* the `<select>`.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I removed the /, but the option is empty

Comment: Are you re-using `$query1` for both loops (the initial select and the javascript function to add additional selects)? If so, you need to reset it before the second loop by using `mysqli_data_seek($query1, 0);` first. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41197555/1941241)

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm sorry to ask this but where do I put the line?

Comment: Anywhere **before** the second `while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query1))`, as long as it's within a `<?php` `?>` part.

Comment: The "Add More" button stops working. I tried to put it before the <script> line within a php tag and next to <select> tag

Comment: I posted an answer combining both answers, see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems.

1. The reason your `<option>` is rendering outside your `<select>` is because you're using a self-closing `<select />` tag. You need to remove the `/` from `<select name="name[]" />`.
2. You're re-using `$query1` for two loops. You can't do that without resetting the internal pointer (the pointer inside your result object that keeps track of which row you've requested). You can do that by using `mysqli_data_seek($query1, 0);` anywhere before you start your second `while` loop.

This would make your javascript code like this (I split the PHP code out into multiple lines for readability):

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var i=1;  
    $('#add').click(function(){  
        i++;  
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><select name="name[]"><?php
            echo "<option SELECTED DISABLED>SELECT CUSTOMER</option>";
            mysqli_data_seek($query1, 0);
            while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
                echo "<option value=\\'$result[description]\\'>" . $result['description'] . "</option>";
            }
        ?></select></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
    })
});
```

**Edit**: A bit more about problem **1**:

Browsers are very forgiving when it comes to invalid HTML code. They see your self-closing `<select />` followed by `<option>` and a `</select>` and they think "Oh, well, that initial `<select />` should have been a `<select>` then" and render it correctly. However, when you're manipulating the DOM directly using Javascript (in this case, by using jQuery's `.append()` function), all that error-correcting logic is skipped and you have to do it correctly the first time.

**Edit 2**: Since you're using single quotes for the `.append('[...]')`, you're getting a conflict with the `<option value='[...]'>` inside that string. The single quotes for the `<option>` need to be escaped. Since `\` is an escape character in PHP, you need to double-slash them.

Comment: the mysqli_data_seek($query1, 0); line stops the add more button from working. But without this line, it creates a new line of <select>

Comment: Does your browser's console give any syntax errors? Or do you have any customers with a `'` character in the `description` column?

Comment: I have neither of them... want me to send the .php file?

Comment: Every browser has a developer console, most can be opened by hitting F12

Comment: oops my bad. It says: 

Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
sample.php:41 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Right, that first one can pretty much be ignored but the second one is important. If you view your page source, what does that append line look like?

Comment: It is highlighted with red:

$('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><select name="name[]"><option SELECTED DISABLED>SELECT CUSTOMER</option><option value='Industrial Blower'>Industrial Blower</option><option value='Bolta'>Bolta</option><option value='3 cm Bolts'>3 cm Bolts</option><option value='Industrial Blower'>Industrial Blower</option><option value='Nuthead 15x14'>Nuthead 15x14</option><option value='Yerong Mahaba'>Yerong Mahaba</option></select></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');

Comment: Ok, took me a second but I figured it out. Since your Javascript string is enclosed in single quotes, you have a conflict with the single quotes in your `<option value='[...]'>` parts. Those need to be escaped. I'll update my answer.